# Uable to use Apache calcite to connect to Gemfire 9.x using third party DB app

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data-gemfire, apache-calcite

I am using a third party application hosted on tomcat which allows only jdbc connections for querying database.
In the new datasource configuration wizard, I have inserted the below details

`URL: jdbc:calcite:model=/someLocation/jdbcConnectionModel.json`

`Driver: org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver`

/someLocation/jdbcConnectionModel.json content:

```
inline:
{
  version: '1.0',
  schemas: [
     {
       type: 'custom',
       name: 'TEST',
       factory: 'org.apache.calcite.adapter.geode.rel.GeodeSchemaFactory',
       operand: {
         locatorHost: 'serverUrl', 
         locatorPort: '10150', 
         regions: 'testRegion', 
         pdxSerializablePackagePath: 'org.apache.calcite.adapter.geode.domain.*' 
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

I have copied following jars in tomcat's lib folder which the app can access:

```
calcite-geode-1.17.0.jar
calcite-core-1.17.0.jar
commons-compiler-jdk-3.0.9.jar
```

But it gives an error:

> Error testing connection, verify DataSource configuration and try again: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver'

Is there something I am missing?

I have tried from java code and it works:

```
public class RelationalJdbcExample {

final static String geodeModelJson =
        "inline:"
            + "{\n"
            + "  version: '1.0',\n"
            + "  schemas: [\n"
            + "     {\n"
            + "       type: 'custom',\n"
            + "       name: 'TEST',\n"
            + "       factory: 'org.apache.calcite.adapter.geode.rel.GeodeSchemaFactory',\n"
            + "       operand: {\n"
            + "         locatorHost: 'serverUrl', \n"
            + "         locatorPort: '10150', \n"
            + "         regions: 'testRegion', \n"
            + "         pdxSerializablePackagePath: 'org.apache.calcite.adapter.geode.domain.*' \n"
            + "       }\n"
            + "     }\n"
            + "   ]\n"
            + "}";


public static Connection getGemfireConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.put("model", geodeModelJson);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
    return connection;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Statement statement;
    try {
         Connection connection = getGemfireConnection();
         CalciteConnection calciteConnection =
                    connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
        statement = calciteConnection.createStatement();
        String query= "SELECT \"a\".\"testAttr\" FROM \"TEST\".\"testRegion\" AS \"a\" ";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);


        System.out.println("resultSet===="+resultSet);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(metaData.toString());
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The above code fetches data from the cache and returns it correctly. Please help.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. The most common explanation is that you don't have the driver (or one of its dependencies) on your runtime classpath, so check that first (eg they must be deployed in the tomcat lib folder, or in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your WAR file).

Comment: that third party app gives me just that much exception. Nothing in logs. I tried putting the above mentioned 3 jars in tomcat lib and WEB-INF/lib. But got the same error.